# Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0-rc01

Tags: android, gradle

when I tried to begin my first Android project, I got this a problem with this message

[A problem occurred configuring root project 'My Application'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0-rc01.][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIemi.png)

```
this is my build.gradle file 


buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0-rc01'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I have downloaded the latest gradle version 6.4.1.
I also tried to change the repositories to all the following:-

```
-repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

-repositories {
        google()
    }

-repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
```

None of them worked

I am using a Psiphon Vpn (I'm not sure if it's related)

i'm using intellj IDEA 2020.1.1

[and I'm using Gradle 6.4.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYOMi.png)

I've used android studio 3.6.3 but it did work either.

I hope you can help me

Comment: What is your current studio version?

Comment: My current android studio version is 3.6.3

Answer (score 0):

Use `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'`

Comment: it didn't work. I also tried to change it to a lower version (as recommended in some answers in this site but it didn't work). Maybe I should Declare repository providing the artifact as mentioned in the first uploaded photo in the question, but I don't know how.

Comment: The repositories are correctly given. Did you try changing the gradle version?

Comment: I have downloaded Gradle 5.5 and unzipped it and changed the settings from Build, Execution, Deployment using the specified location of the Gradle 5.5. I also changed the project structure Gradle version to 5.5. unfortunately, it didn't work.